# C# getting file size of an FTP file in a while loop

Tags: c#

I am writing a program which lets me easily upload a file (drag file over exe) to my FTP server.

While the upload is in progress, I am trying to get the already uploaded file size in another thread.

This works exactly 2 times (caching?), then it just stops giving me feedback of the actual file size on the FTP server.

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://drop.buto.ch/" + file));
req.Method = "HEAD";
System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
int ContentLength;
if (int.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out ContentLength))
{
  return ContentLength;
}
```

or this

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
wc.OpenRead(new Uri("http://drop.buto.ch/" + file));
Int64 bytes_total = Convert.ToInt32(wc.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]);
return bytes_total;
```

I have also tried achieving this with `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize` but this wouldn't let me access the file in Binary mode, instead its going over the ASCII way which is returning me an Error (550).

How can I get the file size on the FTP more than two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example of performing the ftp transfer and getting it's ongoing progress (assuming that is what you are trying to achieve) at the following address:

http://tim.mackey.ie/FtpWebRequestWithProgressBarCFtp.aspx

It will most likely give better results than attempting to get the partial files content size through a http server.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I've already seen this, but i am working with a console app, so there is no progressbar

Comment: You can ignore the progress bar of course and simply review the code which generates the progress text. You can see this in the example image placed next to the progressbar

Comment: ah I see, wasn't really looking at the code, thanks alot, i will try to implement this. And yet i would like to know why I couldnt get the file size more than 2 times over a WebRequest/Client, any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that the http server either caches the size or simply can't compute/access it. Partial files are odd things, the stream could be being cached by the FTP deamon in memory and not being flushed directly to the file.